# Remove undesired characters in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
const array = {FSES: {empId: '322344BD', address:'North'}, DSER:{empId: '322344BD', address:'West'}}
```

I want to be able to get rid of FSES and DSER.
This is my desired array:

```
const desiredArray = [{empId: '322344BD', address:'North'},{empId: '322344BD', address:'West'}]
```

This is what I have tried but it is not working.

```
const newArray = [].concat(...array.map(o => o.address))
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: console.log(Object.values(array))

Answer (score 8):

Your code is not working because you are trying to map over an object. We can use .map() only with array.

You can simply use Object.values for that,

```js
const array = {FSES: {empId: '322344BD', address:'North'}, DSER:{empId: '322344BD', address:'West'}}

console.log(Object.values(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const array = {FSES: {empId: '322344BD', address:'North'}, DSER:{empId: '322344BD', address:'West'}}
const new_array = Object.keys(array).map(item => array[item])
console.log(new_array)
```

Loop through the original object's keys and then get those keys' respective values using `map`